# printing output to webpage from python and receive input from webpage and process to python

Tags: javascript, html, flask

> This is the python file

```py
@app.route('/processor', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chatbot_response():
    msg = request.form['question']
    ints = predict_class(msg, model)
    if ints == int(0):
        ints = str(ints)
        ints = list(map(int,ints))
        ints.clear()

    if (len(ints) == 0):
        ints = [{"intent": "no_other_symptoms", "probability": "1.0"}]
        sorry = {'Sorry, I cant\'t understand what you mean.', 'Sorry! Can you type another word?'}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        prediction = getPrediction(ints)
        list_of_intents = intents['intents']
        result = ints[-1]['intent']
        if (result == 'no_other_symptoms'):
            result = "Hi, sorry to say that I can't find related diseases in your case."
            print(result)
        else:
            for i in list_of_intents:
                if (i['tag'] == result):
                    if (len(symptoms_list) == 0):
                        result = random.choice(i['responses'])
                        # print(result)
                    elif (len(symptoms_list) < 2 and result != 'no_other_symptoms'):
                        result = random.choice(i['responses'])
                        print(result)
                        inp_moresym = input().lower().strip()
                        if 'no' in inp_moresym:
                            result = "I have diagnosed your symptoms and I guess you are having "
                            result += prediction['detected_disease_probabilities'][0]['disease'] + " . "
                        else:
                            abc = predict_class(inp_moresym, model)
                            # tmp = []
                            for result in abc:
                                ints.append(result)
                            prediction = getPrediction(ints)
                            result = "I have diagnosed your symptoms and I guess you are having "
                            result += prediction['detected_disease_probabilities'][0]['disease'] + " . "
                    elif (len(symptoms_list) >= 2):
                        index_highest_disease_probability = prediction['detected_disease_probabilities'][0]['index']
                        for rule in rules[index_highest_disease_probability]:
                            if (int(rule) not in detected_rules):
                                result = "Hi, based on my dataset, people that have your symptoms are also have " + \
                                         symptoms[int(rule) - 1] + " , do you also feel it? symtoms no: " + rule
                                print(result)
                                user_input = input().lower().strip()
                                if 'yes' in user_input:
                                    ints.append({'intent': symptoms[int(rule) - 1], 'probability': 1})
                                    prediction = getPrediction(ints)
                                    result = "I have diagnosed your symptoms and I guess you are having "
                                    result += prediction['detected_disease_probabilities'][0]['disease'] + " . "
                                if 'no' in user_input:
                                    result = "I have diagnosed your symptoms and I guess you are having "
                                    result += prediction['detected_disease_probabilities'][0]['disease'] + " . "

    return jsonify({"response": result })
```

My question is how to i print the result to the web page rather inside the python, and then let the user enter again the input from web page and bring back to python?

```py
elif (len(symptoms_list) < 2 and result != 'no_other_symptoms'):
      result = random.choice(i['responses'])
      print(result)
      inp_moresym = input().lower().strip()
```

> This is the index.html

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <form action = "/processor" method = "POST">
         <p><input class="form-control" type = 'text' name = 'question' id ="question"/></p>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit-button">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p id="response"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>


      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {  // #for id ,$ for access jQuery
          e.preventDefault();


          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/processor", //connect to flask
              data: {
                  question: $("#question").val()
              },
              success: function(result) {
                $("#response").append("<br>Me: "+$("#question").val()+ "<br> Karabo: "+result.response);
                $("#question").val("")
              },
              error: function(result) {
                  alert('error');
              }
          });
```

[Sample image of input message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXwo8.png)

[The list of symptoms are less than 2, it will require the input from user, but it is in the python and not in the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpABF.png)

This is the program of chatbot in healthcare, first the user will input the symptoms, while the list of symptoms are less than two, the system will tell the user to input more symptoms.

Comment: My question is how to i print the result to the web page rather inside the python, and then let the user enter again the input from web page and bring back to python?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the value to be printed on the webpage, then you will have to return the value to the js and use DOM manipulation to show on the webpage.